# Windows Server 2008 r2 as a Digital Audio Workstation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

If windows server is optimized for background servies would that make it optimal for a DAW since  DAWs have to be optimized for background services to give priority to asio drivers and sound to reduce latency

Comment: short answer - yes